# how to port .NET application to mono

Tags: c#, mono, cross-platform, monodevelop

Since I was not satisfied with my C# application not working on Linux or Mac, I installed MonoDevelop in hopes of porting my application to Mono for cross-platformability.

However, I don't know how how to use MonoDevelop to accomplish this task. There's no instructions in FAQ or Documentation.

Any idea how to do it?

Comment: You don't need MonoDevelop for this, you need to test on Linux. http://mono-framework.com/MoMA will help you get started.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

From `MonoDevelop` [FAQ](http://monodevelop.com/FAQ#Can_I_import_my_Visual_Studio_2K5.2b_project_into_MonoDevelop.3f):

> ### Can I import my Visual Studio 2K5+ project into MonoDevelop?
>
> MonoDevelop can open, manipulate and save MSBuild-based projects
> directly in most cases. In fact, since MonoDevelop 2.0 the default
> project format has been VS2008-style MSBuild projects, but VS2005 and
> VS2010 formats are also handled.

Google is still your friend:

- [How to port your .Net applications to Linux using Mono tools for Visual Studio](http://www.slideshare.net/NOVL/how-to-port-your-net-applications-to-linux-using-mono-tools-for-visual-studio)
- [Using Mono to port a C# .NET app to OS X?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4862149/using-mono-to-port-a-c-sharp-net-app-to-os-x)

Comment: I already read the first one, but it just stated that you can port your VS projects to MonoDevelop which I already knew. The last 2 links you provided are just what I want though, so thanks!