# C# app made on VS, can be ported on OSX running VS for Mac?

Tags: c#, macos, visual-studio, xamarin

So I am writing an app that run on Windows (no iOS, no Android, not web...an app for the desktop OS); I like the visual studio environment and in C#, doing visual elements and forms is a breeze, due the fact that I am used to it since early 2000.

Then I realized that Microsoft has a partnership with Xamarin (their new "Visual Studio for OSX"); and since from what I recall, Xamarin use C# via Mono; I thought that I may be able to write the app on Windows and make also a target to build it on OSX via VS OSX.

Is this possible, and most of all, simple to do? I did a search online and I see plenty of case with Android and iOS, but not much on the desktop side. I am so used with products like Unity3D, that sometimes I give in to the assumption that cross platform is nothing so dramatic in 2017 (although reality at times show otherwise).

Which is the best way to work on both platforms, using Visual Studio on Windows and on OSX?

Comment: I know; VS for OSX is Xamarin studio basically. I am looking for a way to import a working project from Windows VS, to OSX VS; and ideally, work back and forth on both platforms, so I have one code repository for both Windows and OSX

Comment: Well, it says "share up to 90% of code" ... no idea what that means.

Comment: As of today, You can use `Xamarin.Mac` to create a macOS-based app using the Mac's native UI frameworks to define your user interface. Within this app you can reference/consume assemblies that define your business logic and model that are shared with your UWP based app. There is currently on going work to add a macOS target to  `Xamarin.Forms` (maybe an alpha/beta in the next month or two or three ;-) Review the `Xamarin.Mac` and `Xamarin.Forms` products: https://www.xamarin.com/platform

Comment: @l'L'l I think they focused mostly on Android-iOS side; especially because people feel bad working in Xcode with Objective-C, or want to use more familiar languages, other than Swift. My app is heavily form-based; which is why I hope I can share code among the 2 platforms...otherwise I have to use a different language and get into the usual multi-platform headaches

Comment: It all depends on the project; I like Objective-C and Xcode, VS to me is strange (the newer one), but it's really all about what works for someone :)

Comment: Absolutely; I came from a 6 years Xcode experience as platform, for both iOS and OSX, and I would rather chop my fingers, instead than use that again :) Or I could pick Java, and use Eclipse on both; althought it is not a very enticing solution.
VS is not perfect or better; just the IDE that I used the most, and I feel comfortable with.

Comment: @SushiHangover, is Xamarin able to read the form that I make on VS, or do I have to re-make the whole view part of my app? I was hoping that I can write the view and model once; and eventually modify the controller where needed; but it seems that you can't share views among VS OSX and VS Win :(

Comment: @newbiez No, you can not share a **native** "View" between the platforms but if you use an GUI abstraction layer like `Xamarin.Forms` than you can include those `Xamarin.Forms`-based Views into an `Xamarin.Mac` app just like developers are doing with UWP/Android/iOS apps right now. `Xamarin.Forms` supports UWP, Android and iOS today and there is "early alpha" support for macOS but it is not currently in a "released" package form, but it is all OSS so you could build the entire `Xamarin.Forms` framework from source to use it to produce macOS-based Forms apps if you are brave at heart :-)

Comment: Desktop applications can only be ported to Mono at this moment, which means existing threads like http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8213461/how-to-port-net-application-to-mono still apply. It would not be surprising that you should use Xamarin.Mac to rebuild the UI while sharing non-UI code between Windows and Mac. BTW, Xamarin has been acquired by Microsoft if you don't read any news in 2016.

Comment: I see; so I did misread the statement that you could port projects from VS Win to VS OSX, including UI, Forms after all are an abstraction of Windows WM, so I was not expecting forms in VS OSX, but I was hoping that UI and event would be converted in their OSX equivalent for most part. I have to account for the UI work then; it is not much, but it may be substantial in the long run

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Porting WinForms Application to Mac OS](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/22661589/porting-winforms-application-to-mac-os)